# How can we setup Cypress for IE and Edge?

Tags: internet-explorer, automation, cross-browser, microsoft-edge, cypress

I need to use Cypress for testing angular and react application on Internet Explorer and Microsoft edge. I have gone through some links which mentions that Cypress supports only Chrome, Chromium and Electron. Is it true ? if not the how can i use it for testing IE and Edge.?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As per the documentation Canary, Chrome, Chromium and Electron are supported.

[Cypress supported browsers](https://docs.cypress.io/guides/guides/launching-browsers.html#Browsers)

Which means you cannot make a test with IE or present Edge browser.

But you can try to make a test with new **MS Edge Chromium**. As it is using Chromium browser engine, It should work with Cypress.

The pre launched version is available to download. You can download it from link below.

[Download link for new Edge Chromium](https://www.microsoftedgeinsider.com/en-us/download/)

Answer (score 3):

Yes it is true, currently only Chrome, Chromium and Electron are supported. You can follow https://github.com/cypress-io/cypress/issues/310 for the strategy of Cypress.io for new browser support.

So to answer the question:

> how can i use it for testing IE and Edge.?

You simply can not

Answer (score 1):

Cypress released Cross browser support in February 6, 2020 in their [4.0.0 update](https://docs.cypress.io/guides/references/changelog.html#4-0-0).

The [list of supported browsers](https://docs.cypress.io/guides/guides/launching-browsers.html#Browsers) is now updated with a few more browsers.

Answer (score 1):

> **At the moment Cypress already supports MSEdge, but not supports IE**.
>
> You can check [Cypress supported browsers](https://docs.cypress.io/guides/guides/launching-browsers.html#Browsers)

Cypress team has been working on Support for Cross Browser Testing. And currently we should have in mind two things:

1. On February 7th, 2020 was realesed Firefox and Edge Support in Cypress 4.0 [more info](https://github.com/cypress-io/cypress/issues/310)
2. **There is an active proposal for IE 11 Support**, and the work required has been in someway considered. [more info](https://github.com/cypress-io/cypress/issues/6423#issuecomment-590735156)