# Cypress on other browsers

Tags: internet-explorer, firefox, cypress

How can I run my cypress tests on Internet Explorer and Mozilla, I'm currently working with Chrome.

Is there any way like Selenium

`driver = webdriver.Chrome("C:\\drivers\\chromedriver.exe")` for Cypress script to IE

Comment: You should not compare cypress with selenium at all

Answer (score 1):

The browser argument `cypress run --browser argument*` can be set to `chrome`, `chromium`, `edge`, `electron` and `firefox`.

You can find cypress exact documentation about this topic here: https://docs.cypress.io/api/commands/request.html#Arguments

Answer (score 0):

As per the documentation Canary, Chrome, Chromium and Electron are supported.

[Cypress supported browsers](https://docs.cypress.io/guides/guides/launching-browsers.html#Browsers)

Which means you cannot make a test with IE or FireFox browser.

As a work around, you can try to make a test with new **MS Edge Chromium**. As it is using Chromium browser engine, It should work with Cypress.

**MS Edge Chromium** has IE mode which lets user to load site in similar way as IE browser.

The beta version is available to download. You can download it from link below.

[Download link for new Edge Chromium](https://www.microsoftedgeinsider.com/en-us/download/)

Reference:

[How can we setup Cypress for IE and Edge?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56052764/how-can-we-setup-cypress-for-ie-and-edge)